# Prevent users from seeing other user's uploaded pictures

Tags: django, django-media

I have a django applications that uses multi-users. Users can upload pictures on the system.I have created a picture model that has a foreignKey of a users to know which user uploaded which picture.

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #other specific fields like date etc
```

I have set up my settings file to use the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'path/to/media/'
```

So I am able to access a picture in `www.mydomain.com/media/pictures/picture.jpg`. But I guess having a common MEDIA_ROOT means that any user can see this picture right?Not just the user who uploaded it. In my webpages I use

```
<img src={{image.picture}}>
```

to show images of a user. How can I prevent a user from seeing a picture a different user has uploaded(a forbidden message)? Can this be done on setup?

Answer (score 0):

Your view function probably looks something like this:

```
@login_required
def theview(request):
    ...
    image = Picture.objects.get(*args)
    ...
    return render(request, 'template', {'image': image})
```

The point being that you can easily only pass the image along if it's the logged in user that have uploaded it. For instance

```
image = get_object_or_404(Picture, uploader=request.user, other_filters)
```

Or even

```
image = Picture.objects.get(*args)
image = image if image.uploader == request.user else None
```

Then in the django template

```
{% if image %}
<img ....>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: yes but that won't restrict another user from entering the following url: www.mydomain.com/media/path_to_image and see my Image. What about  web pages that display all images of a user using <img src={{MEDIA_URL}}/{{image}}> How will I still achieve this. Should I deactivate media serving to user "theview" you proposed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

in views:

```
def allpicture(request):
       .....
       #for all pictures
       images= Picture.objects.filter(uploader=request.User)
       return render(request, '/sometemplate', {'images': images})


def onepicture(request, pic_id):
      ....
      #for one picture
      image= Picture.objects.filter(id= pic_id, uploader=request.User) #url for this view should be like url(r'^pictures/(?P<pic_id>\d+)/$'
      render render(request, '/sometemplate', {'image': image})
```